# Second highest grade for each student

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

```
ID_S    STUDENT_ID  GRADE
1   1   22
2   1   33
3   1   44
4   1   55
5   2   66
6   2   22
7   2   33
8   2   44
9   3   55
10  3   66
11  3   22
12  3   33
13  4   44
14  4   55
15  4   66
16  4   22
17  5   33
18  5   44
19  5   55
20  5   66
```

I have to extract second highest grades for 5 students (each having four different grades). The table should look like this:

```
Student_id  Grades
1             44
2             44
3             55
4             55
5             55
```

but instead, the grade for the first student comes as 55.

this is my code:

```
select student_id, max(grade) as "second highest grades" from grade_list7 
where grade not in (select max(grade) from grade_list7)
group by student_id;
```

What exactly is wrong here?

Comment: `What exactly is wrong here?` Your where clause says `WHERE grade <> the maximum grade Of All Students`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like the `RANK()` analytic function here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT g.*, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY student_id ORDER BY grade DESC) rnk
    FROM grade_list7 g
)

SELECT student_id, grade
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 2
ORDER BY student_id;
```

The issue of two or more grades being tied may be important here, and you might want to use `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `RANK()`, depending on the behavior you want.

Answer (score 2):

Your subselect needs to get the max for the specidifc user, so you need to add the stundet id

Or you can use the RANK approach or Maybe DENSE_RANK

> ```
> select student_id, max(grade) as "second highest grades" from grade_list7 g7
> where grade not in (select max(grade) from grade_list7 WHERE student_id = g7.student_id)
> group by student_id
> ORDER BY student_id;
> ```
>
> ```
> STUDENT_ID | second highest grades
> ---------: | --------------------:
>          1 |                    44
>          2 |                    44
>          3 |                    55
>          4 |                    55
>          5 |                    55
> ```

> ```
> WITH CTE AS (
> SELECT 
> student_id,grade, RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY student_id ORDER BY grade DESC) rn
> FROM grade_list7)
> SELECT 
> student_id,grade FROM CTE WHERE rn = 2
> ```
>
> ```
> STUDENT_ID | GRADE
> ---------: | ----:
>          1 |    44
>          2 |    44
>          3 |    55
>          4 |    55
>          5 |    55
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0ce83b5117585874794855ba8a03c36b)*

Comment: ROW_NUMBER won't work correctly if there are duplicate "top" grades per student. RANK is, probably, better option.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this may work:

```
SELECT student_id, MAX(grade) AS "Second Highest Grades"
FROM grade_list7
WHERE grade < (SELECT MAX(grade) FROM grade_list7)
GROUP BY student_id;
```

Comment: Perhaps not. Subquery has to be correlated, otherwise you'll get all grades that are lower than overall MAX grade in the table (i.e. not per student).

Comment: Thank you. I put perhaps because I was on my phone and had not run it. Thank you for catching it.

Comment: You should delete this answer as it is objectively wrong.